# Redis Lua Script Return Table and parse object

Tags: c#, lua, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a problem,

```
local searchkey=@searchkey
local blockKeys = redis.call('keys', searchkey)
local table = {}
for i = 0, #blockKeys, 1 do
    local seats = redis.call('HVALS', blockKeys[i])
    table[i] = seats
end
return table
```

I want parse this table data for .net obj
I used `StackExchange.Redis` library and lua return `RedisResult` but lua table data isn't parse `RedisValue[]`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: DO NOT USE `KEYS`. Ever. Seriously, never ever do that. At a push, you can use `SCAN`, but that should only be used for admin purposes such as DB analysis tools. The first thing to do is to *not depend on scanning the keyspace*. A good rule of thumb would be to use the config file to rename the `KEYS` command to `KILL_SERVER`; Now; Lua tables should (according to the [`EVAL` documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval)) be mapped to a multi-bulk reply, so the actual *shape* should already "just work". What do you get back? What happens?

Comment: I didnt understand, Why I dont use **keys** , can you explain it to me ? Because I check performance, and **keys** is better than **scan**, and for table, hvals return binary object so => key, { {key, obj}, {key, obj}}

Comment: I've edited my answer to address that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RedisResult` is a general purpose wrapper for data of an unknown shape. There are operators that allow you to interpret the data in a range of ways, for example:

```
RedisResult val = ...

// simple
int asInt = (int)val; // a single integer
string asString = (string)val; // a single string

string[] asStrings = (string[])val; // a table of strings
double[] asDoubles = (double[])val; // a table of doubles

// more structured

var asKeys = (RedisKey[])val; // a table of keys
var asValues = (RedisValue[])val; // a table of values
var asMulti = (RedisResult[])val; // a table of general purpose values
```

So you can *probably* just cast it to what you need. However: using `KEYS` in the script is a big problem and you should really change that.

---

To address the question from comments:

> Why I dont use keys , can you explain it to me ? Because I check performance, and keys is better than scan, and for table, hvals return binary object so => key, { {key, obj}, {key, obj}}

To quote from the [redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys):

> **Warning**: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code.

Each redis instance has a single-threaded core for serving requests. `KEYS` looks *fine* on small databases, but *with or without a filter* the performance is O(N) where N is the **total** number of keys in the database, and for large systems: it can be *catastrophically* bad - meaning: taking 10s of seconds to return. Usually, redis operations are expected to take *milliseconds at worst*, and while your `KEYS` operation runs: **nothing else can**. It *totally* blocks the server for that period.

You note that `KEYS` is more efficient than `SCAN`, and *in some ways* that is true. The entire point of `SCAN` is that it allows you to do the operation as a (potentially very long) series of *small batches* - "scan the first 100; now scan the next 100 from there; and the next 100". This has a *lot* more overhead and latency, and involves more round-trips to the server, but the advantage is that it doesn't block the server core for a single huge chunk of time.

However! Usually, a better approach to *either* of these is to use a *set* of the things that you expect to match your data. Let's say that you have a big database and you're interested in all the `/foo/{whatever}` data. Now; rather than using `KEYS` or `SCAN` to find those values, *if you need* to iterate all the keys in that family, it is viable to simply drop all the **keys** into a set. So when you create `/foo/abc` you also drop `/foo/abc` into the *set* `/foo/_keys` (or whatever; there is no convention here) via `sadd`. Now: to iterate all the keys in that family, you just iterate the *set* `/foo/_keys` - which is a *much* more appropriate API.

Answer (score 2):

```
var asMulti = (RedisResult[])val;
foreach (var item in asMulti)
{
     var asd = (RedisValue[])item;
}
```

my script return table and I think this is RedisResult[] and inside obj 
so design

`"key, { {key, obj}, {key, obj}}"`